# Import file from parent folder

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, spfx, sharepointframework

I'm need to import files from parent folder in Typescript using Visual Code. But I tried use '..' and the file cannot imported. What can do this?

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUZt1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the Data folder is not in the parent folder. You shouldn't need the ../ in that case